# float parsing is returning exponential. But I need to return float value without converting into string format

Tags: c#, .net

Declaring a float value. After parsing that float value I am getting the exponential result.

```
//declaring a float variables
string value = "0.00005";
                
// use of Single.Parse() Method
float value1 = float.Parse(value);
        
//return the value
// return value1 as 0.00005 not as 5E-05

//Output: 5E-05      
//Expected Output: 0.00005
```

Comment: A float has no format just a float shown as string has one. So show what `//printing the value` does since the problem is there.

Comment: Try `value1.ToString("N5")` or `value1.ToString("F5")`

Comment: You should not blame `float.Parse`: it returned the correct value (`0.00005 == 5e-5`), if you want to output the `value1` using custom format use *formatting*, e.g. `Console.WriteLine($"{value1:0.############}");`

Comment: 5E-05 **is**  0.00005. The `float` value has no display format, it's a binary value.

Comment: want to return the value1 as in float datatype only as value 0.00005 only. Is there any way we can parse without converting into string again.

Comment: You're not taking in what people are telling you. A float internally can be thought of as two integers (one number plus a scaling factor) plus a sign bit and some special encodings for NaN, etc. It's not *capable* of storing *what your desired format is when you turn it into a string*

Comment: @AnkurGupta floats, doubles, bytes, integers have no format at all. They're binary values, not strings. Formats apply *only* when parsing text into those binary values, or formatting the binary values into strings. `value` isn't a float, it's a string. Your own code parses it into a float using one format.  It's your own (missing) code that formats the float value as `5E-05`. If you want a different format, specify it in the code you use to generate `5E-05`, eg `value1.ToString("N5")` instead of `value1.ToString()`

Comment: Are you confusing the debugger's display for some actual format? Where did you see `5E-05`? What code produced this?